# Calculate the total of values in text boxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a screen on my ASP.Net page, which, depending on a selection by the user, they get offered between 1 and 5 text boxes. These boxes allow the user to type in an amount.

When the user enters the screen, based on certain criteria, a certain number of these edit boxes are displayed. They are not hidden... if I want 3 boxes, then only 3 boxes are on the screen.

In javascript, as the user types in an amount, a 'Total' edit box is displayed, summing up the values from each box.

So, as the user types, the value in the total updates with the total calculated for all text boxes:

I use:

```
onkeyup="calculateTotal()"
```

on the editbox.

To do that, I use the code below:

```
function calculateTotal() {

        var amt0 = $('.txtAmount0').val();
        var amt1 = $('.txtAmount1').val();
        var amt2 = $('.txtAmount2').val();
        var amt3 = $('.txtAmount3').val();
        var amt4 = $('.txtAmount4').val();


        var amt = Number(amt0);
        if (!isNaN(amt1))
            amt += Number(amt1);

        if (!isNaN(amt2))
            amt += Number(amt2);

        if (!isNaN(amt3))
            amt += Number(amt3);

        if (!isNaN(amt4))
            amt += Number(amt4);

        $('.txtTotalAmount').text('$' + amt);

    }
```

The first issue is that it seems I am losing some precision in the calculation:

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting a strange rounding issue, when all I am doing is summing up.

Additionally, it seems a bit dirty, if I added more boxes, I need to modify the code.

Is there a better way for this code to work?

Comment: Please learn to use a loop… You have discovered the limits of IEEE 754 numbers. ;-) Surely someone can find a good duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can something like this:

```
  var sum = 0;
  $("input[class*='txtAmount']").each(function() {
           if ($.isNumeric($(this).val()) ) {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
        }
    });

   $('.txtTotalAmount').text('$' + sum.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Your answer should include why the OP has the issue and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: I just showed him how to do in a better way, is that no enough?

Comment: I am not going discuss about decimal foundation that goes back to Organisation Unit topic - CPU calculation, of a master degree.

Comment: @Craig you can also use toFixed  after every sum as Number(...) has its own definition that you would like to see on the next.

Comment: The OP is none the wiser as to why the issue occurred. You just need to say that ECMAScript uses IEEE 754 values that can't accurately represent all decimal fractions but that rounding the final result to 2 decimal places fixes it.

Comment: Thanks codebased! That worked. I also read about the cause, and most of it went over my head, but something about all numerics are numeric literals, and treated as 64bit floats? Strange why it get's it wrong though - but your solution (Loop and fix) fixed it.